# cocos2d slow touch detection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am programming iOS using cocos2D. My game runs at 60fps BUT the touchesMoved Function is not being called as fast, In fact it is very slow. It works perfectly on the simulator but not on my device.

The touchesMoved function gets triggered in the simulator at 20fps but goes down to 5fps on the device. Even though I have moved my mouse/finger the same 200 pixels on screen.

I was also using the accelerometer delegate. If I disable this the touch is getting detected normally on the device. Any workarounds because I want to use both accelerometer and touch.

Yes I am using ccTouchesMoved and yes I did change the updateintreval for UIAccelerometer reduced it to 30 but behavioud doesnt change.

Comment: I am using UIAccelerometer class. Will it make a difference If I use CMMotionManager?
A: I used it and it worked fine but I dont want to use it since it requires iOS 4+. Anybody?

Comment: Are you using cocos2d's builtin functions (ccTouchesMoved)? Did you change the UIAccelerometer updateInterval? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html